# Dynamic URLs using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic-url

I'd like to convert a URL like

```
http://mysite.com/search/search_mgmt.php?CategoryID=1
```

to something like

```
http://mysite.com/search/my-seo-friendly-url
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? If somethings gets to your site with `search/search_mgmt.php?CategoryID=1` and you want to convert it to `search/my-seo-friendly-url`, you will have to redirect traffic to another URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/search/search_mgmt.php?CategoryID=1$ http://mysite.com/search/my-seo-friendly-url [R=301,L]
```

With this rule, the server will send the client code `301 Moved Permanently` with `Location:` header set to the new URL. You can change 301 code to 302 (Found): `[R=302,L]`. (Note: in this case the client sends two requests to your server to get the content.)

If you don't add this result specifier, then your server will just return the result as if it was accessed with re-written URL. So I guess you actually would like users to see your `my-seo-friendly-url` whereas on the server it would be handled by `search_mgmt.php?CategoryID=1`. You can do it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/search/my-seo-friendly-url$ http://mysite.com/search/search_mgmt.php?CategoryID=1
```